# Why is IBN not a Morita property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If a ring $R$ satisfies the property $P$, but the matrix rings $M_n(R)$ do not satisfy $P$, then $P$ is not a Morita property; that is the definition.

But that is not fix this situation. I want to know the reason that Invariant Basis Number (IBN) is not a Morita property. (IBN means that $R^m=R^n$ implies $m=n$).

Comment: In other words, you want an example of a ring $R$ that has IBN, but with a matrix ring $M_n(R)$ that does not have IBN? (What does "does not fix this situation" mean?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lam's **Lectures on Rings and Modules** (GTM 189, Springer-Verlag 1999) contains in the exercises an example attributed to George Bergman that shows that IBN is not a Morita invariant property (exercise 11, page 502).

(Lam also mentions earlier in the book that Cohn's book, *Free Rings and their Relations*, contained an exercise asking the reader to prove that IBN was a Morita invariant property...)

Anyway, here's the sketch: Given a ring $R$, let $\mathcal{P}(R)$ be the monoid of isomorphism classes of finitely generated right $R$-modules under the direct sum operation.

It can be shown (using coproducts) that there is a ring $R$ for which $\mathcal{P}(R)$ is generated as a monoid by $[R]$ and $[M],[N]$, together with the defining relations $[M]+[N]=[R]=[R]+[R]$.

Assuming this holds, $S = \mathrm{End}_R(M\oplus N)$ is Morita equivalent to $R$ and has IBN, but $R$ does not (since $R\cong R\oplus R$). To show that $S$ has IBN, the suggestion is to use the following exercise:

> Let $S=\mathrm{End}(P_R)$, where $P_R$ is a progenerator over the ring $R$; then $S$ has IBN if and only if $P^n\cong P^m$ as right $R$-modules implies $n=m$.

Comment: Yes,I just read this book,but the question is not self-contain,suppose a claim without proof,maybe that is really complicative.

Comment: @Strongart: I'm having a bit of trouble parsing your comment. Are you saying that the *answer* is not self-contained (given the reference to to a paper by George Bergman), that the existence of the ring $R$ with the given property is claimed but not proven, and that it is possibly very complicated to give the explicit example?

Comment: Yes,I hope maybe there is another

Comment: Yes,I can not find the paper and hope maybe there are some other simple way,so I ask the question because that is really amazing.